# Deriving the curve of a cantilever

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential-energy, variational-principle, structural-beam

Essentially, there is a beam of length L and negligible mass sticking out of a wall with a mass Mg hanging at the end of it. We are given an equation for elastic energy (which I don't think needs to be modified), and we have to come up with the potential energy contribution from the mass, and then hopefully be able to minimize the energy using variational techniques.

The elastic energy per unit length can be approximated to be $U[y]=\int_0^L \frac{1}{2} EI (y'')^2 dz$ If I can properly define the potential energy of the mass, I think I can do the rest, but I can't figure out the right term. Thanks for reading, and please comment if there is more I should add, including my work involved getting the (incorrect) gravity terms.

Comment: Adding some more detail about how you got the incorrect terms (even just a few lines) certainly couldn't hurt. :-)

Comment: I solved it! -mgy(L) is the potential term. I'll type up the solution tomorrow.